# Windows 8.1: Remove Sharepoint link

Tags: sharepoint

I once had installed a Link to a Sharepoint service on my Windows 8.1 PC. I'm not sure which programm I used. Most likely OneNote 2013 or Outlook 2013.

Now this sharepoint resource is not provided anymore for me. However, every time I reboot a window is poping up and aks me for credentials.

I have not found out, where which app wants to log in. And where to remove this link.

Any Idea?

Comment: I had a similar problem once. I found an old task that tried to connect to a a resource no longer available. Try checking tasks, mails, calendar entries, and contacts, maybe you'll find your entry there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix it using this tool:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3038627